# How to add a new column in output csv with name derived from input file?

Tags: r, csv, data.table, tidyr, rbind

I have multiple txt files stored in different folders. 1 folder for each city. Each txt file contains data at an interval of 5 minutes. I run following code to obtain daily data successfully.

```
for (idx in seq_along(dirlist)){
  filelist <- list.files(path = dirlist[idx], full.names = TRUE, recursive = TRUE, pattern = 
                       ".txt$")
  dt_ <- read_the_files(filelist)
  dt.tidied <- adj_col_names(dt_)

  #bind 
  merged <- rbindlist(dt.tidied, fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
 
  #Selecting the columns to be present in the output    
  selected_column <- c('YYmmdd', 'Temp', 'Pres')

  #Calc daily avg
  avg_dl <- merged %>%    
    group_by(YY_mm_dd = lubridate::floor_date(`YYmmdd`, "1 day")) %>% 
    summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if(sum(is.na(.x)) > 5) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%  
    write.csv(paste0(dirlist[idx],"_dl.csv"))

}
```

This code gives me output files named as CityName_dl.csv. For example, if a folder name is NYR, then its txt files names would be NYR_2020_01_01.txt, then, daily averaged output file would be named as NYR_dl.

I want to add a new column i.e., City_Name to the output file and it should contain first alphabets of input file name such as NYR for all the rows, in th example above. Similarly, output file of folder 'KAN' will have City_Name column filled as KAN. I hope that I have clarified myself well. Please let me know if there exists any doubt.

I tried to use cbind() but no success. Could anyone please help me with this.

Comment: Adding `City_Name` to `group_by` should suffice, e.g. something like `group_by(YY_mm_dd = lubridate::floor_date(`YYmmdd`, "1 day"), City_Name = !!dirlist[idx])`. The exact code depends on the class of *dirlist* etc.

Comment: Why not just `City_Name = dirlist[idx]`? No need for `!!`, it isn't an indirect reference.